How to generate XRay Vulnerabilties report using rest api - how to filter by latest image?
i can succesfully generate the report with the command below, however is there a way to filter it by latest image?
curl -u <user>:<password> https://artifactory.<org>./xray/api/v1/reports/vulnerabilities -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @report.json 
report.json
{
    "name": "docker-prod-local",
    "resources": {
        "repositories": [
            {
                "name": "docker-prod-local"
            }
        ]
    },
    "filters": {
        "severities": [
            "Critical",
            "High"
        ]
    }
}

so the way my repo is structured is,
repository
    folder1
       version1
       version2
       version3
    folder2
       version1
       version2
       version3
    folder3
       version1
       version2
       version3

so what i need to do is in the report only insude latest version of images.
I couldn't find any documentation on if there is a way to filter based on latest images.

I would like to ask what exactly do you need from the report?
I wrote a python script that might assist here that is using the Get Artifact REST-API instead of the reports/vulnerabilities REST-API. It contains less data but still have all the vulnerabilities
Here is the script:
import requests
import os
import json

def get_artifacts(art_url, access_token, repository_name):
    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer" + " " + access_token}
    offset = 0
    list_of_packages = []
    list_of_data = []

    while True:
        offset_string = "/xray/api/v1/artifacts?num_of_rows=1000&repo=%s&order_by=created&direction=desc&offset=%d" % (repository_name, offset)
        get_artifacts_api = art_url + offset_string
        response = requests.get(get_artifacts_api, headers=headers)
        json_object = response.json()
        list_data = json_object['data']
        for index in range(len(list_data)):
            if list_data[index]['package_id'] not in list_of_packages:
                list_of_packages.append(list_data[index]['package_id'])
                list_of_data.append(list_data[index])
        if json_object['offset'] == -1:
            break
        offset = json_object['offset']

    return list_of_data


if __name__ == "__main__":

    art_url = os.getenv("ART_URL")
    access_token = os.getenv("ACCESS_TOKEN")
    repository_name = os.getenv("REPOSITORY_NAME")

    if art_url is None or access_token is None or repository_name is None:
        print("Require ART_URL and ACCESS_TOKEN and REPOSITORY_NAME env")
        exit()

    list_of_data = get_artifacts(art_url, access_token,repository_name)
    file_path = "output.json"
    with open(file_path, "w") as json_file:
        json.dump(list_of_data, json_file, indent=4)

Let me know if it helps.

not exactly what I am looking for but it helped in some other way, it would have been a lot easier if there was a way to filter based latest artifact.
